# I am trying to setup a form using jQuery click method

Tags: forms

I am trying to setup a form using jQuery click method. For html I don't want to use onClick but rather call from the id clickMe to display name. It doesn't seem to be working. Is this possible? if so, What am I missing?

```
var getName = function ()
{
if (document.getElementById("FirstName").value == "" || document.getElementById("LastName").value == "")
{
return ("Please enter your first name and last name.");
}

else {var fullName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("LastName").value;
return fullName;
}
}

var displayName = function () 
{

    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        alert(displayName());
    }); 
}); //end ready

}
```

HTML

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="">  

 <p class="FirstName">  
    <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  </p>
    <p>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" />  

</p>  

<p class="LastName">  
    <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label></p>
    <p>
    <input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName" />  

   </p>


<p class="submit">  
    <input name="submitButton" type="button" id="clickMe" value="Display Name" />
  </p>  
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See acdcjunior's answer for a correct analysis of what is wrong with your existing code. In fact I think your `displayName` function is redundant here and you could simplify things considerably by updating your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var getName = function () {
        if (document.getElementById("FirstName").value == "" || document.getElementById("LastName").value == "") {
            return ("Please enter your first name and last name.");
        } else {
            var fullName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("LastName").value;
            return fullName;
        }
    }

    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        alert(getName());
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried getName earlier and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It's possibly out of scope because it's declared outside the jquery ready callback function. Try the code in my edited answer above.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either. looks like i forgot the ready function according to your code. I can get to work using onClick in html but not using id.

Comment: yes...for some reason it doesn't work in my file but works on jfiddle. I must have a conflict somewhere in my file. Thank you! I will have to figure this out.

Comment: By the way, acdsjunior's analysis of the problems with your current code is completely correct, mine is not. I think my simplification of the code should suffice though.

Answer (score 2):

You see, this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#clickMe").click(function(){
      alert(displayName());
   }); 
});
```

Is inside `displayName`:

```
var displayName = function () 
{
...
}
```

And `displayName` is never called. Thus the `click()` event is never set up.

Either take that `$(document).ready()` code outside, or place a call to `displayName`, like this:

```
var getName = function ()
{
    if (document.getElementById("FirstName").value == "" || document.getElementById("LastName").value == "")
    {
        return ("Please enter your first name and last name.");
    }
    else {
        var fullName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        return fullName;
    }
}

var displayName = function () 
{
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#clickMe").click(function(){
            alert(displayName());
        }); 
    }); //end ready

}

$(function() { displayName(); }); // <-- calling displayName here!
```